# SyntaxError when adding to a global set inside a function (Python)

Tags: python, set, global-variables, shadowing

I am trying to write a function that reads keywords from a file (in the format that each keyword is on a new line inside the text file)

I want the function to put the keywords into a global set() called "desiredItems".

```css
desiredItems = set()

def populateDesired():
    for line in open("desireditems.txt"):
        addableLine = line.rstrip("\n")
        global desiredItems.add(addableLine)
```

For some reason my development environment (Pycharm) tells me that desiredItems.add is invalid syntax.

(sorry If I have inserted code snippet incorrectly etc)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would imagine `set.add()` returns `None` so essentially you are using `global None`. You should just use `global desiredItems` and do the add on the next line. Although I would strongly recommend not using `global` and passing the set in as a parameter.

Comment: @IanAuld, that would be a runtime error. In fact `global` must be followed by one or more _identifiers_, so the `.` causes it to be a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `global` at all, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the binding of a global variable, the syntax is like this

```
def populateDesired():
    global desiredItems
    for line in open("desireditems.txt"):
        addableLine = line.rstrip("\n")
        desiredItems.add(addableLine)
```

Since you are not modifying the binding - merely calling a method, there is no need for `global` here at all

```
def populateDesired():
    for line in open("desireditems.txt"):
        addableLine = line.rstrip("\n")
        desiredItems.add(addableLine)
```

Comment: thank you. I had "modifying the binding" confused with "modifying the set".